# meaning of "the way I get it, it's optional"

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I know the meaning of the bolded expression in the following excerpt of a conversation, but I cannot understand how it is related to it.

> Man: Hi. Listen, I was just wondering whether you understood what
>   Professor Carson was saying about the review session next Monday?
>
> Woman: Sure. Why?
>
> Man: **Well, the way I get it, it's optional**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*get* means *understand* here. So think of it as:

> Well, the way I *understand* it, it’s optional.

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get - see definition 11d)

Comment: As I said I know "get" means "understand". But the problem is here that the man asks the woman to sure if she's understood about something. Then the woman answers "sure, Why? (asking the man why he wants to know that?)". Then the man says that expression "Well, the way I understand it, it’s optional."

Comment: Ok, sorry, I assumed the word “get” was what you were confused about. The man asks the woman if she understands what the professor has said about the review session. The woman says she does (“sure”) and asks why the man brings it up. The man says as he understands it, the review session is optional. The point of saying this is to get the woman’s agreement. He expects her to then say “Yes, that is also my understanding” so that he can feel justified in skipping the review session. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Yes, it was exactly the thing that I was confused about it.